# how to convert WebView into IRandomAccessStream in UWP?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

What i have Tried is?
My Xaml code :

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <Button x:Name="but" Content="Click" Click="but_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

My C# code:

```
    private async void but_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebView x = new WebView();
        x.Width = 100; x.Height = 100;
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        await x.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync(ms);
    }
```

when I try to convert Webview to Stream.It throws an error like this.
[image]

I don't why this was happening .Can Anyone suggest me , How to convert webview to IRandomAccessstream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `WebView` has not rendered into xaml visual tree. we need to insert `WebView` into Page content before calling [`CapturePreviewToStreamAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.capturepreviewtostreamasync?view=winrt-19041) method.

```
private WebView x;
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    x = new WebView();
    x.Height = 100; x.Width = 100;
    RootGrid.Children.Add(x);
}

private async void bookmarkBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await x.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync(ms);
}
```